# Azure - Web API and Route Template with a Regular Expression

Tags: azure, iis, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got a .NET Core application which is running a small web API.

The following route works without any troubles.

### Working HTTP Route

```
[HttpGet("api/voting/{id:int}")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(Voting))]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByIdAsync([FromRoute] int id)
{
    // Left out for the sake of brevity ...
}
```

### Non Working HTTP Route *(only on Azure)*

```
[HttpGet("api/voting/{slug:regex(\\w+)}/full")]
[MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(Voting))]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBySlugAsync([FromRoute] string slug)
{
      // Left out for the sake of brevity ...
}
```

### Error Message in Azure

[image]

### Troubleshooting

- Everything works perfectly well if I run it on my local environment, the problem only appears once I run it in Azure.
- Within the `Requested URL` the port `80` is appended, which I don't really understand as I only communicate via https with the service. Could it be that the regular expression is interfering with the port suffix?
- The `Physical Path` for some reason appends the route to the `wwwroot` directory. Does this mean that the route couldn't be resolved properly?

  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

404 error might caused by route issue. Since you are using route attribute for your Web API. Please make sure `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` is above other code.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

And `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` code is above other routes configuration.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "versionApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In addition, try to delete following code in your Controller to test whether it is related to the dependent injection module.

```
[Dependency]
public IConfigurationServicev2 configurationService { get; set; }

[Dependency]
public IAccountService accountService { get; set; }
```

If it also can't work for you. You could get the detail error message from web server after setting `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` property in `WebApiConfig` class.

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```